# Run Apex Code when campaign status is changed to Completed

Tags: apex, field-update

we would like to run an Apex Code when the user changes the campaign status field to Completed.
What is the best way to do that without stressing the system?

I saw it is possible to do it with triggers but I do not want it to run anytime the campaign is updated.

Answer (score 0):

That's literally what triggers are designed for. A trigger that runs but "does nothing" will run in literal milliseconds. Hardly any stress at all. Your code would look like this:

```
Campaign[] completedCampaigns = new Campaign[0];
for(Integer index = 0; index < Trigger.size; index++) {
  if(Trigger.old[index].Status != Trigger.new[index].Status && Trigger.new[index].Status == 'Completed') {
    completedCampaigns.add(Trigger.new[index]);
  }
}
if(completedCampaigns.size() > 0) {
  YourApexClass.doSomething(completedCampaigns);
}
```

(Of course, it'd be better as a [trigger framework](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/33134/2984), this is only illustrative).

This code will run in sub-millisecond time if there's only one campaign being updated and it doesn't match the criteria, or about 10-20 ms for 200 records in the list (based on some tests I wrote up to try it out). That's not even 1/10th of one second.

You could also use a Flow with an Apex Action, but realistically, that's overkill for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi sfdcfox, Thanks for your answer. This is exactly what I was looking for. We are not only trying to run an Apex codee but also perform some outgoing API Request to an external API. Is there a Time Limit within using triggers that we need to take into concern?

Comment: @MarcBl. You can't make callouts in a trigger context. This limitation is in place to both prevent excessive resource contention and to ensure that roll backs won't affect external systems. You'll end up using a future/queueable method to perform the callouts after the trigger runs to completion.